# What can you do with AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID without also having AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY?

Tags: amazon-web-services

All the documentation about AWS keys seems to always tell you to have both the key id and the secret key. Are there any practical uses to have only the key id *without* the secret key? If not, why aren't the two combined into one ever so slightly more manageable single setting?

Seems to me if you must ask the user to produced the secret you might just as well ask for *their* own key id as well in the process.

Comment: Allowing actions to be taken based off of the Access key alone would kind of defeat the point wouldnt it? For example, in this system if i had your access key, i could spin up 10,000 quadruple extra large instances and in a matter of seconds cost you $10,000+

Comment: Yes, revealing the secret is a bad idea. What good is the (presumably) public key id by itself?

Comment: The 'public key' serves merely as an identifier for your account so AWS knows what account to perform the actions on. The secret key acts as part of a signing mechanism to identify that the request is authorized.

Answer (score 2):

More general: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

All Amazon APIs only work with the access key + signature. The signature is the way you prove you also have the secret key. The secret key never goes over the wire.

If you would "combine" them in the same key you would not know what account the request is for. You would also have to send the secret key over the wire which, in general, is a very bad thing.
So basically the public (access) key servers as an account selector and the private key serves to prove you actually have access to the account.

Comment: I'm well aware of what the key components do together. I'm asking if there are any uses to have only the key id. Combining the parts in a single setting in no way dictates what goes over the wire as the app/lib can always extract the parts it needs, like from a CSV file row.

Comment: technically, you cannot extract the secret key by design. the access key is used on the server side to identify the account for which the operation is happening (i.e. user id)